# Problem with attachments' character encoding using gmail gem in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, gmail

**What I am doing:**
I am using the gmail gem in a Rails 4 app to get email attachments from a specific account at regular intervals. Here is an extract from the core part (here for simplicity only considering the first email and its first attachment):

```
require 'gmail'

Gmail.connect(@user_email,@user_password) do |gmail|
    if gmail.logged_in? 
        emails = gmail.inbox.emails(:from => @sender_email)
        email = emails[0]
        attachment = email.message.attachments[0]
        File.open("~/temp.csv", 'w') do |file| 
            file.write(
                StringIO.new(attachment.decoded.to_s[2..-2].force_encoding("ISO-8859-15").encode!('UTF-8')).read
            )
        end
    end
end
```

The encoding of the attached file can vary. The particular one that I am currently having issues with is in Finnish. It contains Finnish characters and a superscripted 3 character.

This is **what I expect to get** when I run the above code. (This is what I get when I download the attachment manually through gmail user interface):
[image: This is what I expect to get (and what I get when I download the attachment manually)]

**What the problem is:**

However, I am getting the following odd results.

From `cat temp.csv` (Looks good to me):
[image: This is from a cat temp.csv (looks good)]

With `nano temp.csv` (Here I have no idea what I am looking at):
[image: This is what it looks like with nano temp.csv]

This is what temp.csv looks like opened in Sublime Text (directly via winscp). First line and small parts look ok but then Chinese/Japanese characters:
[image: This is what temp.csv looks like opened in Sublime Text (via winscp)]

This is what temp.csv looks like in Notepad (after download via winscp). Looks ok except a blank space has been inserted between each character and the new lines seems to be missing:
[image: what temp.csv looks like in Notepad]

**What I have tried:**

I have **without success** tried:

- `.force_encoding(...)` with all the different "ISO-8859-x" character sets
- putting the `force_encoding("ISO-8859-15").encode!('UTF-8')` outside the `.read` (works but doesn't solve the problem)
- encode to UTF-8 without first forcing another encoding but this leads to `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`
- writing as binary with `'wb'` and `'w+b'` in the `File.open()` (which oddly doesn't seem to make a difference to the outcome).
- searching stackoverflow and the web for other ideas.

**Any ideas would be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Not beautiful, but it  will work for me now.

After re-encoding, I convert the string to a char array, then remove the chars I do not want and then join the remaining array elements to form a string.

```
decoded_att = attachment.decoded
data = decoded_att.encode("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace).gsub("\r\n", "\n")

data_as_array = data.chars
data_as_array = data_as_array.delete_if {|i| i == "\u0000" || i == "ÿ" || i == "þ"}
data = data_as_array.join('').to_s

File.write("~/temp.csv", data.to_s)
```

This will work for me now. However, I have no idea how these characters have ended up in the attachment (`"ÿ"` and `"þ"` in the start of the document and `"\u0000"` between all remaining characters).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to do `attachment.body.decoded` instead of `attachment.decoded`

Comment: Thanks. It seems actually that attachment.body.decoded and attachment.decoded return the exact same string. I check both the strings and their arrays of bytes.